# For a random variable $Y = Z/W$, why is $f_{Y\mid W}(y \mid w) = wf_Z(wy)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function

In my book, one way to find the conditional density $f_{Y\mid W}(y \mid w)$ of the random variable $Y = Z/W$ is by taking $W = w$ as a constant and computing $wf_Z(wy)$. I’m wondering intuitively, why this works? I’m having trouble seeing how this is connected to the formal definition $f(y \mid w) = \frac{f(y,w)}{f(w)}$.

Edit:

I posted a sample problem in my book (Mathematical Statistics 7th Edition by Wackerly et. al) below. In this example, $T = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{W/v}}$ is a t-distribution with $v$ df. Hence, $Z$ is a standard normal random variable and $W$ is a $\chi^2$ distributed variable with $v$ df. $Z$ and $W$ are independent.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This usage in which one uses the same notation for different functions is obnoxious. There is a difference between $f_X(3)$ and $f_Y(3),$ and when one writes $f(x) = \text{some expression involving } x,$ it is intended to be true of EVERY value of (lower-case) $x$, so that $f(3) = \text{that same thing with $3$ where $x$ was}.$ The (capital) $X$ as a subscript identifies a random variable; the lower-case $x$ is something for which $3$ or any other number can be substituted.

Comment: I think crucial information are missing. Please check if you´ve provided all relevant information.

Comment: I think the missing crucial info is that $Z, W$ are independent.  To prove this result, do we need anything else besides $Z, W$ independence?

Comment: My apologies, I added a sample problem from my book that will hopefully make things more clear @callculus

Comment: @Yandle It´s not a good idea to wait one day to clarify a question. Now your question is put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an *intuitive* (i.e. non-rigorous) explanation.

If we were dealing with discrete variables and probability masses, then

$$P(Y=y \mid W=w) = P(Z = wy \mid W=w)$$

Nice and obvious.  But when dealing with continuous variables and probability densities, a change of variable requires a re-scaling.  Intuitively:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_{Y|W}(y|w) = P(Y \le y \mid W=w) &=& P(Z \le wy \mid W=w) = F_{Z|W}(wy|w)\\
{d \over dy} F_{Y|W}(y|w) \times dy &=& {d \over dz} F_{Z|W}(wy|w) \times dz\\
f_{Y|W}(y|w) \times dy &=& f_{Z|W}(wy|w) \times dz\\
f_{Y|W}(y|w) &= &f_{Z|W}(wy|w) \times {dz \over dy}\\
&=& f_{Z|W}(wy|w)\times w\\
&=& w \times f_Z(wy) \,\,\,\,\, \text{if $Z,W$ independent}
\end{array}
$$

Hopefully your textbook did mention that $Z,W$ are independent!  If not, I don't think you can derive $w f_Z(wy)$...

I would not consider the above rigorous, and indeed I don't know enough measure theory to make it rigorous.  If you need a more rigorous proof, hopefully someone else can help.